# Razer Blade Advanced 2019 INSANE SCREEN FLICKER. Works fine on Performance mode and when Plugged in

Tags: laptop, display

I hope someone can help! I have an issue with my brand new Razer Blade 15, every time its plugged in it works perfect without any issues, however when unplugged the screen would flicker like crazy, not brightness changes, the screen physically flashes on and off rapidly making it unusable. I messed around with the power plans and when its on performance mode (power plan) it works perfectly fine. However this causes battery drain on an already below average battery life! Also sometimes the screen flicker would correlate with the movement of the trackpad, if i moved it the screen would flicker, sometimes even if i dont touch the trackpad it would still flicker (balanced power plan)

Specs:

i7 9thgen
2080 maxq
OLED
512gb ssd

I've tried many clean ddu installation of different versions of drivers for the 2080 and also different drivers for integrated UHD630 graphics!

I also tried a clean windows installation.

Also tried all power options on intel graphics control panel.

I don't want to return it to razer as they have big delays in shipment and I'm sure this is a software issue?

Comment: If I helped, please mark my answer as the answer by clicking on the green tick. @Akbar

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue on some laptops, especially with OLED screens. A usually successful quick fix I know of is to disable 'Panel Self-Refresh' in the Intel Graphics Control Panel:

1. Open Intel Graphics Control Panel
2. Select 'Power'
3. Select 'On battery'
4. Click 'Disable' under the heading 'Panel Self-Refresh'

Here is a picture to help:

[image]

Hope this helps.